# SQL query slow when joining with a sub query and only happened for one big Database

Tags: sql, database, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

All my complex stored procedure works instantly for most of DBs,

But it will take more than 30 sec to execute them on DB X, maybe more but we didn't find yet.

DB X doesn't have the most data but our supporter 'delete' some data and re-insert them recently.

I've corrected the table identity Index but it doesn't help.

Then I found when a light table 'Left Join' a sub query which will return the main data, the execution becomes slow.

The sub query itself is quick and also If I insert sub query to a temp hash table and left join the hash table, the query is fast!

Anyone know what happened to this DB X, and the solution ?

I found it caused by missing index, but I don't understand how come now?
I also worried about the speed for inserting a big amount data if set index on server.

Comment: Can you post your query please.

Comment: And the execution plans from running query against different databases.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks

I found it caused by missing index, but I don't understand how come now? I also worried about the speed for inserting a big amount data if set index on server.

Answer (score 1):

Have statistics been updated and indexes been rebuilt? Or disabled?

Especially after a lot of inserts, deletes etc

Comment: Beat me to it with stats. But note that you shouldn't always reach out for the index rebuild, Microsoft recommends index reorganise depending on fragmentation.

Comment: @todda.speot.is : I've found a rebuild can be easier on the log file. (and it's 30% say MS)